# Given array, write a function that returns the item in the array that matches that question

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function, findAnswers(answers, questions) that returns the item in the array that matches that question. If none of the student's answers match the question, return undefined and if more than one of the students' answers match the question, return the first one in the array.

Example output:

```
findAnswer(answers, "True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels."); /*=>
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
*/
```

Given array:

```
let answers = [
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];
```

What I have so far:

```
function findAnswer(answers, question) {
  let result = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    let studentAnswers = answers[i];
    if (studentAnswers === answers) {
      result[answers[i].question]
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I know the code is pretty bad, I'm just not sure how to return an array of matching responses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to find an element in an array that passes a test, the appropriate method to use is `.find`, which will return `undefined` if no match is found:

```
const findAnswer = (answers, question) => answers.find(
  answer => answer.question === question
);
```

```js
let answers = [
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];
const findAnswer = (answers, question) => answers.find(
  answer => answer.question === question
);

console.log(findAnswer(answers, "True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels."));
```

Comment: Ahh, this is extremely helpful. Thank you so much!